# Azure function returning 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, unauthorized

I have an Azure function app with several functions in it. They were deployed using VSTS source control integration. Everything used to work both locally and in the deployed version.

But now if I change the code, it triggers a build and deployment. Both complete successfully, but I don't see my functions under the function app in Azure portal anymore. So, I manually created the functions again and deployed again. Again the deployment succeeded but I get the following error when I click on the manually created Timer Trigger based C# function.

Note that none of the Service Bus or other application settings have changed in the Application Settings section of the app.

[image]

If I check the streaming logs, I get the following html:

[image]

Comment: If you enable application and web server logging under "Platform Features -> Diagnostic Logs" can you include the log of it trying to start up?

Comment: I enabled the logs, restarted the function app and then clicked on one of the azure functions. This time I got: "The function runtime is unable to start. Session Id: d822e9bbd9a04e45898086d2eb68a563
Timestamp: 2018-01-23T18:50:36.078Z" How do I go to the logs?

Comment: I believe I have seen this happen on occasion. The function's host keys may have been wiped out by something (e.g. a bad deployment) and then the runtime can no longer actually govern the app because the `_master` host key is missing. If you are able to go into the portal you can check this by going to the "Function App Settings" page for the function app and looking under the "Host Keys".

Comment: I am able to see two host keys: _master and default. I can see their values if I click on 'Click to Show'.

Comment: I have added another screenshot in the question.